Qiskit has both <1.0 and >1.0 versions ERROR
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-2-7f9dd94881db> in <module>
----> 1 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
      2 from qiskit_aer import Aer
      3 from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
      4 simulator = Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator")
      5 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\__init__.py in <module>
     34     _suppress_error = os.environ.get("QISKIT_SUPPRESS_1_0_IMPORT_ERROR", False) == "1"
     35     if not _suppress_error and _has_tools:
---> 36         raise ImportError(
     37             "Qiskit is installed in an invalid environment that has both Qiskit >=1.0"
     38             " and an earlier version."

ImportError: Qiskit is installed in an invalid environment that has both Qiskit >=1.0 and an earlier version. You should create a new virtual environment, and ensure that you do not mix dependencies between Qiskit <1.0 and >=1.0. Any packages that depend on 'qiskit-terra' are not compatible with Qiskit 1.0 and will need to be updated. Qiskit unfortunately cannot enforce this requirement during environment resolution. See https://qisk.it/packaging-1-0 for more detail.

I tried to delete the old version but couldn't do it. I would appreciate if anyone can help.

You should create a new virtual environment, and ensure that you do not mix dependencies between Qiskit <1.0 and >=1.0

How did you install qiskit?

qiskit_env\Scripts\activate
pip install qiskit ```
i did this on powershell

Ignore the first point if you have already done this,

First, create a new virtual environment and and install
qiskit>1.0.0 in that environment. You can find the relevant
information in the qiskit documentation
here.

Second, install jupyter-lab in the same virtual environment as qiskit>1.0.0. Now activate the virtual environment and then use jupyter-lab from that environment. If you don't do this then everytime you run jupyter-lab from your base environment you will be using the qiskit version installed in your base environment.


